# Dovecotのプロキシ機能で465番ポートでSSL通信できるようにする方法

Tags: dovecot, mail

お世話になります。
下記サイトを参考にVPSにDovecotをインストールして、外部のメールサーバー（今回の例ではConoHaのメールサーバー）のプロキシとして利用するように設定しました。
[ConoHa のメールサーバーを使おうとしたら SSL 証明書で難儀した話 (実装編)](https://www.compnet.jp/posts/2019-01-05T1737_ConoHa%20%E3%81%AE%E3%83%A1%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%8A%E3%81%86%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89%20SSL%20%E8%A8%BC%E6%98%8E%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%A7%E9%9B%A3%E5%84%80%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E8%A9%B1%20(%E5%AE%9F%E8%A3%85%E7%B7%A8).html)
とりあえず、設定は終わり、大体はうまく動いているのですが、現状だと465番ポートでのSSL通信ができずに困っています。
メーラーから送信しようとすると、下記のエラーが出る状況です。

```
mail.example.com への接続に失敗しました。(FD_CONNECT, code=10061)
```

ちなみに、STARTTLSをオンにした状態で、587番ポートからの送信は成功しています。
465番ポートでSSL通信をできるようにするには、どのようにしたらよいでしょうか。
なお、下記コマンドでポート解放を行ったあと、サーバーを再起動しています。

```
ufw allow 465
```

環境は、Ubuntu 18.04、Dovecot 2.3.7.2です。
以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

なんとか自力で解決したので、メモ代わりに残しておきます。

1. 「/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf」を開き、「service submission-login {」の下に下記を追記する。

   inet_listener submission_25 {
   port = 25
   }
   inet_listener submission_465 {
   port = 465
   ssl = yes
   }
2. Dovecotを再起動する。